# Could I Create One Controller Like Laravel Resource Controller in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, rest, api, controller

So, I have for example this Laravel Resource Controller code like this:

```
class BaseAPIController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return self::$model->all();
    }
}
```

So, I was trying to do like that in ASP.NET C#:

```
[ApiController]
public class BaseAPIController<T> : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>> Get()
    {
        using (ExamRTContext db = new ExamRTContext())
        {
            return db.${typeof(T).Name}.Select(x => x);
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't have any idea how to do like that.

So, Let say I just wanted to do simple CRUD in 3 tables. All operation is same, for example Get() is used to get all data from that model.

Instead of writing it 3 times, I wanted to just write it once and extend it to each model controller.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

C# does not allow you to compose expressions at runtime like that.

However, EF has an API to do this.
You're looking for [`.Set<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform simple CRUD operations with entity framework you could create a generic repository.

**Repository:**

```cs
    public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TContext>
        where TContext : DbContext
        where TEntity : class
    {
        protected readonly TContext context;

        public GenericRepository(TContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public virtual async Task Add(TEntity model)
        {
            await context.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(model);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public virtual async Task<TEntity> Get(int id)
        {
            return await context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
        }

        public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll()
        {
            return await context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public virtual async Task<TEntity> FindFirstBy(Func<TEntity,bool> predicate)
        {
            return await Task.Run(()=> context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(predicate));
        }

        public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FilterBy(Func<TEntity,bool> predicate)
        {
            return await Task.Run(()=> context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToList());
        }

        public virtual async Task Update()
        {
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public virtual async Task Remove(TEntity model)
        {
            context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(model);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

To be able to use it you just have to inject it in the controller specifying the Entity Type and the Context. In your example it would be like:

**Controller Base:**

```cs
[ApiController]
public class BaseAPIController<T> : ControllerBase
{
    protected readonly GenericReposoitory<T,ExamRTContext> repository;

    public BaseAPIController(GenericRepository<T,ExamRTContext> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>> Get()
    {
        var entities = repository.GetAll();
        if (entities!= null) {
            return Ok(entities);
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

**In Startup:**

```cs
services.AddTransient(typeof(GenericRepository<,>), typeof(GenericRepository<,>));
```